# Virtual Env for nodejs application

Tags: node.js, virtualenv

We are running a nodejs application, but we want to run different version of same application, how we can achieve this, like python virtual environment.

I have seen nodeenv, but from the examples, it seems it only provides different versions of node binary to run, but not nodejs application.

With regards,

-M-

Comment: is the application created in different Version of Node?

Comment: Application created same version of node, but I want to install different version of same application running same version of node.

Comment: You can run two instance of the server in two different ports, is there any problem in doing like this?

Comment: I have same need like you - as a python-based engineer, working with nodejs make me have the need nodeenv working similarly as pipenv for local project folder

Answer (score 0):

When you have different versions of the same app, I assume that you will have a different package.json file for each version of the app? And you probably have the different version of the app resides on different folder?
Are you in a Linux environment or windows or Mac?

Can you use a .sh/bat  to invoke the npm start on different folders ?

Comment: I am using Linux environment, I do not bother about the package.json as the node_modules dependencies may not be changed across different versions of this application. And the thing is how I can copy it to different directory, as the package is an debian package and while installing it will install to specific directory, now how I can install some different version of the same app.

Comment: Sorry,  I probably do not understand your requirements. How do you track the different version of your app? Where did you source control them   We can use package.json and indicate a version number of the application   e.g. if you look at all the external modules in the public npm registry, They have many different versions, We can install them using npm is:  e.g               npm install ws@1.2. npm install ws@.1.3